# How to find the ideal chunk_time_interval in TimescaleDB

Tags: timescaledb

I test same tables in timescaledb with various chunk_time_interval and i was wondering how i can  set the ideal chunk_time_interval.In timescaledb documentation it says "Make sure that you are planning for single chunks from all active hypertables fit into 25% of main memory, rather than 25% per hypertable".